# Impossible to read files inside a dirctory

Tags: php

I have an error appear in strict mode? I look the path of the directory, it's correct. I try to put all files in 777 but same problem.

It seems this line is not read :

```
@dir(Core::getConfig('dir_root', 'Shop') . 'includes/modules/security_check/')
```

The error generated

```
    string(8) "extended" 
    Warning: include(/........./config_file_catalog.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /......./SecurityCheck.php on line 75

    Warning: include(): Failed opening '/......./config_file_catalog.php' for inclusion 

(include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /....../SecurityCheck.php on line 75
```

the code :

```
  if ($secdir = @dir(Core::getConfig('dir_root', 'Shop') . 'includes/modules/security_check/')) {
    while ($file = $secdir->read()) {
      if (!is_file(Core::getConfig('dir_root') . 'includes/modules/security_check/' . $file)) {
        if (substr($file, strrpos($file, '.')) == $file_extension) {
          $secmodules_array[] = $file;
        }
      }
    }
    sort($secmodules_array);
    $secdir->close();
  }
```

Comment: I am very skeptical of `/........./config_file_catalog.php`. I highly recommend 1. spacing your `..` out like `../../..`... and 2. going into your working directory and trying `cat /........./config_file_catalog.php`, and debugging your path that way

Comment: @MyStackRunnethOver I suspect that's just the author hiding the full path. They likely didn't want to broadcast their application's directory structure. (The number of dots being different in various places suggested a human edit rather than raw PHP output.)

Comment: Indeed, the path has been hidden